# Push full file when run the shell script from Flask application

Tags: python, git, github, flask

The size of the file to deploy is: 78KB

Created `deploy.sh` file and when I run it directly on terminal it pushes the file as is. But when i run the same script from Flask application, it only pushes 72KB (or multiply by 8) and its skipping part of the file.

```
cd <PATH TO REPOSITORY PATH>
git add directory/* --force
git pull
git commit -m "updated from bash"
git push
```

`python script`

```
def push_from_local():
    os.system("./commit.sh")
```

Comment: what does `os.system("./commit.sh")` do?

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. I tried to run the command while write the file, thats what the issue happen

the wrong method i've used

```
with open(config_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
        print("Writing to file")
        json.dump(req, outfile, indent=4)
        print("Config file is ready for push")

        github_util.push_new_file_to_github(config_file_name,"DatacloudIntl/dcapi","master","config/column_maps/"+domain_name+".json", False)
```

replaced as this and it works....

```
with open(config_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
        print("Writing to file")
        json.dump(req, outfile, indent=4)
        print("Config file is ready for push")

    github_util.push_new_file_to_github(config_file_name,"DatacloudIntl/dcapi","master","config/column_maps/"+domain_name+".json", False)
```